# Using ModelBuilder Iterator sub-model then append?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, append

I've created an iterator as a sub-model that collects values, then a main model that appends those values together upon completion of all iterations. My issue is if the iterator runs 10 times, then I get 10 appended records of the 10th iteration (the final value) not the 1 - 10 unique values. If I remove the Collect Values function and just add the append function there the model works perfectly, but that isn't suitable since I don't want to have to append each and every iteration to save time:

1) Iterator Sub Model [image]

2) Main Model [image]

Comment: How are you naming the output of the pairwise intersect tool?

Comment: Just "Pairwise_Intersect". Does it need to be inline sub or something like "Pairwise_Intersect%n%?

Comment: Yes. But as you are using the iterator use the value, so use `Pairwise_Intersect_%Value%`. Make sure you are setting the contents and not simply renaming the green bubble (what you see in model builder) you do that by _opening_ it or going into the tool itself.